# Mobile Menu Not Showing

Tags: mobile

I am using the latest version of wordpress with the responsive 2015 theme. The drop down menu doesnt show on mobile - or when the browser window is very small. Its the drop down menu that is three lines. When you click it, it should have a drop down menu.

It works fine on a full desktop screen - but when I shrink the screen (or view it on mobile), the three lines menu does create a drop down. Nothing happens when you click it. Here is the link. Anyone have any ideas? Ive disabled cache

http://www.ladysoma.com/womens-health/shea-butter-faq

Answer (score 1):

Your menu appears to be a Custom Menu Widget instance. You have to add a Nav Menu via the Appearance > Menus section, the button only works with the menu assigned to the Primary Menu location.

Comment: My menu is assigned as primary menu already but it is not clickable in mobile view after updating the wordpress to latest version..what should be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your menu as the 'primary menu'.

To do this go to 'Appearance > Menus' and find the menu that you created. At the bottom check the box 'primary menu'.

This can also be done through 'Appearance > Customize - Primary Menu.

Then go to appearance > widgets and delete the menu widget that you added to the sidebar.

Comment: My menu is assigned as primary menu already but it is not clickable in mobile view after updating the wordpress to latest version..what should be the problem ?